# Typescript: infer types for object properties later

Tags: javascript, typescript

consider the following snippet:

```
interface NameToPromise {
    [key: string]: Promise<any>
}

const nameToPromise: NameToPromise = {}

nameToPromise.someProp = new Promise<boolean>(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(true), 100)
```

If you hover over `someProp`, the typescript compiler shows `Promise<any>`. What I want him to do, is to start as any, but infer that it should be `Promise<boolean>` since this is the value thats assigned to it.

How can I achieve this in Typescript?

Comment: The type of a variable is set and determined during initialization. Further changes don't dynamically change the type automatically. Forced type changes can be done using type assertions with `as` but that's about as far as it goes. Unfortunately, making the type system dynamically track and update types for every variable at every mutation is completely infeasible.

Comment: `as` won't really help since I can't use it at variable assignment sadly